# Apple Universal Dock & Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, dock

Just acquired an azatom Tune-Stream Bluetooth dongle which turns 30-pin iPod docking stations into Bluetooth devices. However, it doesn't work when I insert it in an Apple Universal Dock (connected to a TEAC micro hi-fi system via a small jack). My iPod Touch works in the Dock, and it pairs with the Tune-Stream remotely when that is in place, but no sound. Azatom instructions say doesn't work with speakers with "digital signal interface", but why would Universal Dock have a different interface from usual iPod docking station?

Comment: iOS devices can out either digital or analog audio through their dock connectors. Digital signal interface means that the iPod outputs digital audio to the speakers. Probably your device only works with analog audio output.

Comment: So, are you saying that the Universal Dock is neutral; that it depends on what input the attached sound system demands? If so, that suggests it would work connected to a system demanding analog input ..?

Comment: Yep. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

iOS devices can output either digital or analog audio through their dock connectors. Your hi-fi is only compatible with digital audio. But your Bluetooth dongle outputs analog audio to the hi-fi, which it can’t play.

Comment: Huh? The Universal Dock is an analog device.

Comment: @grahamparks Nope. It is a digital as well as analog device.